# How to implement a TreeSet in Java?

Tags: java

I'm implementing a TreeSet which will sort by person's age, but a person will not be saved in set if person's name is equals. I implement equals and hashcode, but this set will save all persons even if they have the same name. I don't know why.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        if(this.getAge()<o.getAge()){
            return -1;
        }
        return this.getAge() == o.getAge()?0:1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object){
        return name.equals(((Person)object).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Set<Person> set = new TreeSet<Person>();
        set.add(new Person("Jack",30));
        set.add(new Person("Jack",20));
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add

```
if(name.equals(o.getName())) {
    return 0;
}
```

in the beginning of your `compareTo()` function. That way TreeSet can assume `a.equals(b)` is equivalent to `a.compareTo(b) == 0` and you still get the ordering by age as all names in the set are different.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. equals and compareTo have to do "the same thing". That is, if equals returns true, compareTo should return 0 and vica versa.

Comment: is there any way to use set sort element by age but compare the same element by name?

Comment: Use a custom comparator for the `TreeSet`?

Comment: Comparator should compare by age first, then by name - that's it!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the implementation of `TreeSet`, it can only contain unique elements. To store these elements in the `TreeSet`, the implementation will *compare* new elements with the existing once using the `compareTo()` method.

You code is currently saying - *Person is equal by name, but only comparable by age*

I suggest that you either change the `equals()´,`compareTo()`and`hashCode()` method to take name and age into account.

To sort your `Person` objects by age, i would recommend a `ArrayList` and sort it by a custom `Comparator`

Comment: you mean set can't sort by age and compare by name?

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of `Set` (of which `TreeSet` inherit):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html:

> sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2)

But `TreeSet` also must (from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface

So, your `compareTo()` method should check if two `Person` are `equals()` by `name` first, and if they are not, check their `age`.