# Java Collection framework TreeSet

Tags: java, collections, string-comparison, treeset

In TreeSet class of Collection framework, how do the two strings namely "Shiv" and "Shiva" will be compared as in this case "Shiv" does not have fifth letter and before that all are same as of "Shiva"?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Isha : If you want to know internal working of treeSet from the point of curiosity then you can refer:

http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/10/how-treeset-works-internally-in-java-interview-questions.html

And, if you want some custom implemetation then you can refer :

[How to implement a TreeSet in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118303/how-to-implement-a-treeset-in-java)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`Shiv` will come before `Shiva`, which is the normal collation order for `String` objects.

Assuming you have a `TreeMap<String,SomeClass>`, keys will be ordered based on the `String#compareTo()` method which is present because `String` implements `Comparable<String>`.

Comment: yes that i have found out through coding but how is the comparison going internally in TreeSet as by default compareTo() method is called.

Comment: or u r saying that Latin alphabet scheme is followed in case of Strings

Comment: @Isha Why do you care about the internals of TreeSet? It works fine doesn't it? Or are you trying to accomplish something else like writing your own version of it?